# Missing storage on macOS Big Sur

Tags: hard-drive, big-sur, storage

I have a 2017 Mac with 250 GB of storage. Recently, I noticed it was all but full.

I scanned the main drive with Grand Perspective and became very confused.

There are 4 folders:

- Apps with 73 GB
- Library with 6 GB
- System with 17 GB
- Users with 37 GB

All told I was able to find 133 GB of data.

However, it appears that I am missing 70 or so GB of data. as the Mac book states that there are only 50 GB of storage left.

Is this:

1. something that has happened before?
2. is it fixable?

Comment: Can you give the result of this terminal commands : `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /`and `sudo du -sxg /System/Volumes/Data/* 2>&1 | grep -v permitted | sort -nr | grep -n 10` The second command may be long to have result. This will permit to see the biggest places on the system volume.

Comment: Diskutility tells me for my mac it has 6 volumes. So are you checking all or just one? Just to be clear I am running the latest Big Sur…